# Subseting in R for uploaded dataframe

Tags: r

It is a class assignment so i can't give the main problem. We have to to subsetting on particular data that is given to us to upload. Suppose we have given it the variable name mydata. It is excel sheet file in csv format. So, we have uploaded it and have done other problems with it. Here is uploaded in that way. mydata <- read.csv(name_of_file)

mydata has six columns with headers. Now, suppose column names are as following: abc efg hij klm nop qrs. Now, the question is like that:

"Extract data where abc value is <50 and klm <100. What is the mean of hij in this subset?"

I know mean is mean(). However, how can i extract all the values at same time as sub table of this big table so i know that both constraints are met and i can see the hij as well so i can take its mean. Please don't show me how to take mean because it is a quiz on exam. I will find it myself. However, please show me how to extract with all these constraints and extract has to be as full subdata so i can see hij. No apply functions please. It is the first test. apply comes in second test.

Answer (score 0):

If `dat` is the dataset

```
subDat <- subset(dat, abc <50 & klm <100)
```

You can find the mean from `subDat` as you described.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to subset is (for original dataset mydata)

```
subData <- mydata[mydata$abc < 50 & mydata$klm < 100, ]
```

This will select all rows in the dataframe where the criteria are met.  The blank after the comma means that all columns of matching rows will be returned (in dataframe subData).

Comment: Thank You. I am sure that your solution works too and i will try it to see. However, i have used akrun answer and it solved my all problems for that quiz. Again, thank you.